# How to uninstall a Windows XP Update

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Since foolhardily installing the latest windows updates, my XP laptop now takes 45 minutes to boot up; ThinkVantage no longer reacts and it took 30 mins to connect to the WiFi.

According to [this](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistawu/thread/73cea559-ebbd-4274-96bc-e292b69f2fd1), there is a problem with patch KB977165 which is causing BSOD for some people, so I want to uninstall it. I have no XP disk around here (it is at work, and today is Saturday...) so can't boot from one.

How can I uninstall the update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be uninstalled from **Add/Remove Programs** in **Control Panel**. Check off the **Show Updates** checkbox at the top of the window:

[image]

The updates will then appear in the list and you can remove them like other applications.